# Raspbian : Apache server cannot upload any files

Tags: php, upload, apache2, raspbian

I'm running an apache2 - php5 server on a RaspberryPi.
When i try to upload a file by a form, it appears that `move_uploaded_file` returns False, and the file is not uploaded, even if it's very small.

I already edited /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini as follows :

```
upload_tmp_dir ="/tmp"
upload_max_filesize = 200G
max_file_uploads = 200
post_max_size = 10G
```

My html form must be correct since the upload system works perfectly on WAMP !
So I really don't understand what the issue is...

Does someone know why `move_uploaded_file` returns False, and why the server can't upload any files ?

Here is the code related to `move_uploaded_file` :

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['user_file'])) { //Upload file submit button pressed
        if ($_FILES['user_file']['error'] > 0) {echo "File could not be transfered";}
        $file_moved_ok = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['user_file']['name']);

        if ($file_moved_ok) {
            echo "<p>File uploaded alright</p>";
        } else {echo "<p>___File was NOT uploaded___</p>";}}
?>
```

Comment: can you provide your full move_uploaded_file code?

Comment: Hi, check if this is a permissions issue in your production server.

Comment: @PeterDarmis "production server", what do you mean ?
What folder(s) should have specific permissions ? I already gave `/tmp` all permissions for everyone at least.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim See my edit ! Does that help ?

Comment: if you have set 0755 or 0777 in `/tmp` folder permissions then check if you must specify the complete `/path/to/tmp` @Ramanewbie

Comment: @PeterDarmis Actually "/tmp" is already the complete path, I choosed to directly use Raspbian's temp folder as that's the temp folder used by my php.ini.

Comment: @Ramanewbie try the same but specify a tmp folder inside your public_html folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move_uploaded_file will move the temp uploaded file from temp location to the destination you choose. you did not set destination directory.
for example:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_file']['tmp_name'], '/detention_full_path/'.$_FILES['user_file']['name'];
```

also, make sure the destination directory (/detention_full_path/) have write permission.